# Google AdSense API asking for log in each time

Tags: authentication, adsense, adsense-api

I've put together the Google AdSense API for earnings which works.  However, I want it to run in the background without me logging in.  It asks me to log in each time it's ran.  I have the offline set as well as store the token.  I'm not sure why it keeps asking me to log in.  I have this running on a nightly cron job on GoDaddy.  Code is below:

```
<?php
include('config.php');

require_once 'templates/base.php';
session_start();

set_include_path('/path/to/clientlib' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
set_include_path('/path/to/clientlib' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/AdSense.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/AdSense.php';
// Autoload example classes.

include 'examples/GetAllAccounts.php';
include 'examples/GetAccountTree.php';
include 'examples/GetAllAdClients.php';
include 'examples/GetAllAdUnits.php';
include 'examples/GetAllCustomChannelsForAdUnit.php';

include 'examples/GetAllCustomChannels.php';
include 'examples/GetAllAdUnitsForCustomChannel.php';
include 'examples/GetAllUrlChannels.php';//GetAllUrlChannels
include 'examples/GenerateReport.php';//GenerateReport
include 'examples/GenerateReportWithPaging.php';//GenerateReportWithPaging
include 'examples/FillMissingDatesInReport.php';//FillMissingDatesInReport
include 'examples/CollateReportData.php';//CollateReportData
include 'examples/GetAllSavedReports.php';//GetAllSavedReports
include 'examples/GenerateSavedReport.php';//GenerateSavedReport
include 'examples/GetAllSavedAdStyles.php';//GetAllSavedAdStyles
include 'examples/GetAllAlerts.php';//GetAllAlerts
include 'examples/GetAllDimensions.php';//GetAllDimensions
include 'examples/GetAllMetrics.php';//GetAllMetrics
// Max results per page.
define('MAX_LIST_PAGE_SIZE', 50, true);
define('MAX_REPORT_PAGE_SIZE', 50, true);
// Configure token storage on disk.
// If you want to store refresh tokens in a local disk file, set this to true.
define('STORE_ON_DISK', false, true);
define('TOKEN_FILENAME', 'tokens.dat', true);
// Set up authentication.
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adsense.readonly');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
// Be sure to replace the contents of client_secrets.json with your developer
// credentials.
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');
// Create service.
$service = new Google_Service_AdSense($client);
// If we're logging out we just need to clear our local access token.
// Note that this only logs you out of the session. If STORE_ON_DISK is
// enabled and you want to remove stored data, delete the file.

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
}
// If we have a code back from the OAuth 2.0 flow, we need to exchange that
// with the authenticate() function. We store the resultant access token
// bundle in the session (and disk, if enabled), and redirect to this page.
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
// Note that "getAccessToken" actually retrieves both the access and refresh
// tokens, assuming both are available.
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    if (STORE_ON_DISK) {
        file_put_contents(TOKEN_FILENAME, $_SESSION['access_token']);
    }
    $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    exit;
}
// If we have an access token, we can make requests, else we generate an
// authentication URL.
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
} else if (STORE_ON_DISK && file_exists(TOKEN_FILENAME) &&
    filesize(TOKEN_FILENAME) > 0) {
// Note that "setAccessToken" actually sets both the access and refresh token,
// assuming both were saved.
    $client->setAccessToken(file_get_contents(TOKEN_FILENAME));
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
// If we're doing disk storage, generate a URL that forces user approval.
// This is the only way to guarantee we get back a refresh token.
    if (STORE_ON_DISK) {
        $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
    }
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}
//echo pageHeader('Get Final Report');
//echo "stre on disk = " . STORE_ON_DISK . "<br />";
echo '<div><div class="request">';
if (isset($authUrl)) {
    echo '<a class="login" href="' . $authUrl . '">Login !</a>';
} else {
    echo '<a class="logout" href="?logout">Logout</a>';
};
echo '</div>';
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    echo '<pre class="result">';
// Now we're signed in, we can make our requests.
    $adsense = makeRequests($service);
    /* Note that we re-store the access_token bundle, just in case anything
    changed during the request - the main thing that might happen here is the
    access token itself is refreshed if the application has offline access. */
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    echo '</pre>';
}
echo '</div>';
echo pageFooter(__FILE__);
// Makes all the API requests.
function makeRequests($service) {
    print "\n";
    $accounts = GetAllAccounts::run($service, MAX_LIST_PAGE_SIZE);
    echo '<div class="Account">Account No. '.$accounts[0]["id"].' Details</div>';

    if (isset($accounts) && !empty($accounts)) {
// Get an example account ID, so we can run the following sample.
        $exampleAccountId = $accounts[0]['id'];
        GetAccountTree::run($service, $exampleAccountId);
        $adClients =
            GetAllAdClients::run($service, $exampleAccountId, MAX_LIST_PAGE_SIZE);
        ;

        ?>
        <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter" border="1px solid">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>AdClient ID</th>
                <th>AdClient Code</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach($adClients as $adClients){

                ?>
                <tr><td><?php echo $adClients['id']; ?></td><td><?php echo $adClients['productCode']; ?></td></tr>

            <?php
            }
            ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <?php

        if (isset($adClients) && !empty($adClients)) {
// Get an ad client ID, so we can run the rest of the samples.
            $exampleAdClient = end($adClients);

            $exampleAdClientId = $adClients['id'];

            $adUnits = GetAllAdUnits::run($service, $exampleAccountId,
                $exampleAdClientId, MAX_LIST_PAGE_SIZE);


            ?>
            <table id="myTable_1" class="tablesorter" border="1px solid">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>AdUnit name</th>
                    <th>AdUnit Code</th>
                    <th>AdUnit ID</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Detail</th>

                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                foreach($adUnits as $adUnits){

                    if($adUnits['status']=='ACTIVE' ||$adUnits['status']=='NEW'){  ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $adUnits['name']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $adUnits['code']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $adUnits['id']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $adUnits['status']; ?></td>
                            <td class="link"><a href="<?php echo $redirect.'?ad_name='.$adUnits['name'];?>">Get detail</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                    }
                }
                ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <?php
            if (isset($_REQUEST['ad_name'])) {
                //die('function shoul be calle dhere ');

                $Get_reports=GenerateReport::run($service, $exampleAccountId, $exampleAdClientId,$_REQUEST['ad_name']);
            }
            else {
                $Get_reports=GenerateReport::run($service, $exampleAccountId, $exampleAdClientId);
            }
            //print_r($Get_reports);

            ?>
            <table id="myTable_2" class="tablesorter" border="1px solid">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <?php foreach($Get_reports['headers'] as $headers){
                        ?>
                        <th><?php printf('%25s', $headers['name']); ?></th>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <?php

                foreach($Get_reports['rows'] as $rows) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <?php
                        foreach($rows as $col) {
                            ?>
                            <td><?php echo $col; $adsense = $col; ?></td>

                        <?php

                        }   ?>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                }
                ?>

            </table>

            <table id="myTable_3" class="tablesorter" border="1px solid">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <?php
                    foreach($Get_reports['headers'] as $headers){
                        ?>
                        <th><?php echo 'Total '.$headers['name']; ?></th>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <?php
                    foreach($Get_reports['totals'] as $totals){

                        ?>
                        <td><?php echo $totals; ?></td>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <?php
            //die('Report Generated For Last 7 Days');


        }
    }
    //echo "adsense = " . $adsense . "<br />";
    return $adsense;
}
```

Comment: Hi Don, if I understood correctly - you were trying to write a code that can take the data without the user interfering? meaning - use the data inside the code? Because I'm trying to do the same - take the reports data and use them - on the background... manipulate them and insert into SQL table... if you could contact me I'll appreciate it :)

Comment: I'm getting some problems while using AdSense PHP api, I want to know that: what do you want to refer by `/path/to/clientlib`  and `config.php`? Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the manual log in once and store the refresh token, subsequent auth requests would use that stored token and won't prompt you again.

It should be as simple as changing this to true and then hitting the page once using the right account.

```
// If you want to store refresh tokens in a local disk file, set this to true.
define('STORE_ON_DISK', true, true);
```